# Gmail extensions mail count is not working

Tags: gmail, google-schemas

The Gmail inbox feed is recently having issues updating. It is only updating after 2 consecutive and different emails have been marked as unread.

This is the official Gmail inbox atom feed API which is having issues as of May 30th and which many extensions are using:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/gmail_inbox_feed

It is affecting all Gmail checking extensions:

- [Google Mail Checker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-mail-checker/mihcahmgecmbnbcchbopgniflfhgnkff) by Google
- [Checker Plus for Gmail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/checker-plus-for-gmail/oeopbcgkkoapgobdbedcemjljbihmemj) by Jason Savard
- and more...

Note, the same issue can also be reproduced by marking emails as read instead of unread.

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Go to Gmail and mark an email as unread
2. Click refresh in the "Checker Plus for Gmail" popup window or wait 1 minute in the Google Mail Checker
3. Go to Gmail and mark **another** email as unread
4. Click refresh in the "Checker Plus for Gmail" popup window or wait 1 minute in the Google Mail Checker

The unread mail count is not correctly displaying the number of unread emails with each mark as unread after refreshing. It only working after 2 consecutive mark as unread on different emails.

Are there workarounds or alternatives that do the same thing, or do I need to wait for Google to fix it?

Comment: As much as I love your extension, this doesn't appear to be a question, which is what this site is intended for - http://stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: I'm a happy user of your extension as well :) But, this does not seem to be a question. Isn't this instead a bug report?

Comment: Can you help direct me to the appropriate channel to raise the flag to the Gmail team?

Comment: It IS a question. The last line, after he explains the issue: "Are there workarounds or alternatives that do the same thing, or do I need to wait for Google to fix it?"

Comment: @Rafe it is a question _now_, but it wasn't before _I_ added the last line to make it a real question about 10 hours ago. The comments (including mine) are from 11 hours ago.

Comment: Thanks for the addition then, @LéoLam. I overlooked the fact that your tag is there as editor.

Answer (score 8):

Here are a few things you can do about it:

1. [Report a technical issue (Gmail)](https://support.google.com/mail/contact/gtag?hl=en)
2. Gmail.com -  Settings/Gear > Help > Send Feedback
3. [Gmail Official Forum > Report an Issue](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!categories/gmail/report-an-issue)

Comment: Thank you, I have opened an issue via option 3 here -  https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/gmail/report-an-issue/qA5CQts0kAM